# ASP.NET username change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an asp.net site which uses the ASP.net Membership provider. Each comment, entry etc in the DB is tracked by the userID.

Since MS doesn't provide a way to change the username, I've found the userNAME in the "users" table in the DB and there is only 1 place where the username appears.

My question is,

Is it safe to provide an "edit profile" page where the user is allowed to edit their own username. Of course i would handle this change in the background by directly changing the "username" value in the DB.

Are there any downsides to this ? I've created and modified some test accounts and it seems to be fine, i am just wondering if there is any known negatives to this before putting it into production.

Comment: We should check fist if any foreign key exist by http://stackoverflow.com/a/1374315/413032. If not exist we should ask (: if someone used it and there is no key. Then we may update user and watch what will be.

Answer (score 14):

cptScarlet's link was good, however I despise using stored procedures if I don't have to and I favor Entity Framework whenever possible. Here's what I did to change the user name, using EF 4.0 and .NET 4.0:

1. Right click project -> Add New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model
2. Give it a proper name, I chose "MembershipModel.edmx" and click Add
3. Select Generate from database and click Next
4. Add the connection to your 'aspnetdb' database (the ASP.NET membership database)
5. Give it a proper name, I chose "MembershipEntities"
6. Click Next
7. Drill into Tables and select aspnet_Users
8. Change the Model Namespace to MembershipModel
9. Click Finish

Now you can add code to create the EF object context and modify the database:

```
public void ChangeUserName(string currentUserName, string newUserName)
{
    using (var context = new MembershipEntities())
    {
        // Get the membership record from the database
        var currentUserNameLowered = currentUserName.ToLower();
        var membershipUser = context.aspnet_Users
            .Where(u => u.LoweredUserName == currentUserNameLowered)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (membershipUser != null)
        {
            // Ensure that the new user name is not already being used
            string newUserNameLowered = newUserName.ToLower();
            if (!context.aspnet_Users.Any(u => u.LoweredUserName == newUserNameLowered))
            {
                membershipUser.UserName = newUserName;
                membershipUser.LoweredUserName = newUserNameLowered;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I did not account for application ID's in my code. I typically only ever have one application using the ASP.NET membership database, so if you have multiple apps, you'll need to account for that.