# SQL Server 2008: Find out primary/foreign key in Table?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how I can see which are the primary & foreign keys in a table?

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses. I was looking for a SQL Query to do that. Right now I'm playing around with writing a tool which can list me all Tables of a DB and show the columns. I'd like to display also which of the keys are primary keys.

This is how I read out the Table Catalog:

```
const string sqlSelectTable = "SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE " +
                                      "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES " +
                                      "WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' " +
                                      "ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE,TABLE_NAME";
```

And this is how I get the Infos about a Column:

```
const string sqlSelectTable =
            "SELECT     COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH " +
            "FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " +
            "WHERE     (TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME) " +
            "ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION";
```

Would I have to create a Inner-Join so see which of the Columns are Primary Key?

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the primary key on each table, you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    kc.name,
    c.NAME
FROM 
    sys.key_constraints kc
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON kc.parent_object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE
    kc.type = 'PK'
```

and for the foreign key, I believe this query should get you the necessary information:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Parent table',
    c.NAME 'Parent column name',
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Referenced table',
    cref.NAME 'Referenced column name'
FROM 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c 
       ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id 
          AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cref 
       ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id 
          AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id
```

Marc

Comment: No that does not work. It returns any indexes you have created.

Comment: @Craig: query #1 **only** returns primary keys - query #2 returns **only** foreign keys - or what do you get??

Answer (score 4):

see the [Querying the SQL Server System Catalog FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx), [How do I find the columns of a primary key for a specified table?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx#_FAQ16) and [How do I find the columns of a foreign key for a specified table?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx#_FAQ17)

EDIT: if you want to do it programmatically (which is not clear from your question), that is.

Answer (score 3):

In Management Studio, expand the table and then expand the Columns item. The primary key(s) has a key icon next to them.

To see the foreign keys, expand the Constraints item.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with:

```
SELECT 
   Table_Name as [TableName], 
   Column_Name as [ColumnName],
   Constraint_Name as [Constraint], 
   Table_Schema as [Schema]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
ORDER BY 
   [TableName], 
   [ColumnName]
```

(you can filter then by tableName)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Parent table',
c.NAME 'Parent column name',
OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Referenced table',
cref.NAME 'Referenced column name'
FROM 
sys.foreign_key_columns fkc 
INNER JOIN 
sys.columns c 
   ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id 
      AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.columns cref 
   ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id 
      AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id  where OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'tablename'
```

If you want to get the foreign key relation of all the tables exclude the `where` clause else write your tablename instead of `tablename`