# Getting the PrimaryKey from a table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, select, primary-key

I am trying to get data from a database using the primary key of that table. The issue is that the name of the primary key for each table will be different.

For example, the user may want to pull up the employee table and the primary key is Emp_ID. Then they want to pull up the manufacturers table and that primary key is Manu_ID.

Since the information is being pulled up in the same ViewModel, everything needs to be dynamic.

Here is my SQL statement that looks at the Manufacturers table:

C#:

```
string strSQLconnection = (connectionString);
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);

tableName = tableName + "AuditLogView";

sqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM @tableName WHERE ManufacturersID = @primarykey", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tableName);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primarykey", primaryKeyID);

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Some of this is already being implemented dynamically, like the primary key from the user and the table name. I think if I can just always find the primary key in my table then it should work. Is there some way to do this? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Do you need to consider tables where the primary key is multiple columns?  A primary key need not be a single column in many database systems.

Comment: Database objects (tables, stored procedures or any other objects) cannot be passed as parameters. Only actual values for columns or variables can be parameters. You need to build your SQL statement dynamically.

Comment: To retrieve the PK of a table, you can base yourself on  the following
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373549/sql-server-2008-find-out-primary-foreign-key-in-table

Comment: @EricLippert I do not need to consider that. They are all set up the same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am not sure I know what you mean by that? I have it working currently by passing the tableName as a parameter, but I need to make it even more dynamic.

Comment: @JLott - what he means is that `FROM @tableName` only works if you happen to have a table *variable* called `@tableName` in scope when you run your query. If you have a *scalar* variable called `@tableName` (perhaps a string containing the *name* of a table), it will produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want create a generic query that will accept table name and column name as parameter?

Try this:

First, create a stored procedure, this stored procedure will create generic query based on the parameter.

```
-- @tabName = table name
-- @colName = column name
-- @colVal = column value
create proc p1 @tabName varchar(100), @colName varchar(100), @colVal varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select * from ' + @tabName + ' where ' + @colName + ' = ''' + @colVal + ''''
    exec sp_executesql @sql 
end
```

Then, call that stored procedure from your code:

```
string strSQLconnection = (connectionString);
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("p1", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabName", "table1");
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colName", "col1");
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colVal", "1");        

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();


sqlConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will get pkey column name:

```
SELECT 
    cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
    cu.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT tc.* 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
            WHERE 
                tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 'dbName' 
                AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' 
                AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
                AND tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        )
```