# Calling a Membership database Stored Proc directly from within an MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-membership

I have an MVC 3 web application using Entity Framework to access the projects database. However, the project also uses a second database for Memberships called ApplicationServices. The MvcMembership package uses this database for authentication purposes. Now, I added a custom stored procedure in the ApplicationServices database that I would like to call from my application. How can I do that?

I guess I could do so by using the Membership Provider, but I am not sure how to do so.

Here is how it is defined in my Web.config file:

```
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=false; Initial Catalog=ApplicationServices; User ID=******; Password=******" />
...

    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" ... applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't call it from the default `SqlMembershipProvider` because this is a custom Stored Procedure and **the Membership Provider know nothing about it**.

Anyway you still could access this stored procedure like normal. Or you may make custom `MembershipProvider` and use this StoredProcedure in it. It depends on what and why you use this StoredProcedure

Comment: I agree! the best bet is to create a separate membership provider. You can use Entity for db connectivity in this provider exclusively. any other solution would look ugly

Comment: @Wahid_Bitar I am working on a system where the username is the email address. ASP.Net's Membership Provider does not provide a way to change the username, so I had to create a stored procedure to do so as described here: [http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070109-1.aspx](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070109-1.aspx) (see ChangeUsername... it is in fact a function).

My problem is similar to the one described here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229730/asp-net-username-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229730/asp-net-username-change)

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid What do you mean by "use Entity for db connectivity in this provider exclusively"? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Then i advice you to make a small service class to change the UserName and in this class you could call your SP "maybe by using EF if you want"