# Change UserName of Membership User in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using email address as username in my application.
Now i want to edit my profile and based on requirement i also want to change my email address also.

**I tries following code but it showed me that username is read only property.**

```
var user = Membership.GetUser("test@test.com");
user.UserName = "new email";
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

Is any other workaround is available in asp.net membership authentication to update username(i.e. email address in my case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET username change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229730/asp-net-username-change)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Entity Data Model by makeing changes to the username field directly.

```
var secure = (from q in dbsecurity.aspnet_Users 
where q.UserName == 'old email'
select q).FirstOrDefault();

if (secure != null)
{
secure.UserName = 'new email';
secure.LoweredUserName = 'new email';
dbsecurity.SaveChanges();
}
```